# Getting blurry image using coil image library

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, coil

Using

```
paint(
                        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(Note.getBackgroundImages()[note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex]),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
```

Image is blurry but application is not lagging, on using

```
paint(
                        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(Note.getBackgroundImages()[note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex], contentScale = ContentScale.Crop),
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
```

Image is sharp but application is lagging.
I am using jetpack compose with coil Image library to load image on lazy column. It is a notes app, which shows all notes in a lazy column and each note can have background image, but app lags if i show background in AllNotesScreen. Backgrounds are in xml file format stored completely offline in res/drawable folder.

This is my complete code for a single note item to be displayed in lazyVerticalStaggeredGrid or lazyColumn. Here is link of github repo --> https://github.com/ayushs-2k4/Notes

```
package com.ayushsinghal.notes.feature.notes.presentation.all_notes.components

import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.combinedClickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ExperimentalLayoutApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FlowRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.paint
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import coil.compose.AsyncImage
import coil.compose.AsyncImagePainter
import coil.compose.rememberAsyncImagePainter
import com.ayushsinghal.notes.R
import com.ayushsinghal.notes.feature.authentication.presentation.signin.TAG
import com.ayushsinghal.notes.feature.notes.domain.model.Note
import com.ayushsinghal.notes.feature.notes.domain.model.Note.Companion.getColors
import com.ayushsinghal.notes.ui.theme.PastelGreen
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Async
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun NoteItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    note: Note,
    onNoteItemClick: () -> Unit
) {

    val noteColor = getColors()[note.selectedColorIndex]

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                color = noteColor
            )
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
            .run {
                if (note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex != 0) {
//                    paint(
//                        painter = painterResource(Note.getBackgroundImages()[note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex]),
//                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
//                    )

                    paint(
                        painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(Note.getBackgroundImages()[note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex],
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
                        ),
//                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )

                } else {
                    this
                }
            }
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                color = if (noteColor == MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background) {
                    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                } else {
                    noteColor
                }
            )
            .combinedClickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = rememberRipple(),
                onClick = { onNoteItemClick() },
                onLongClick = { Log.d(TAG, "Long clicked on note with id: ${note.id}") }
            )
    )
    {
        Column() {

            if (note.tags.isNotEmpty()) {
                TagList(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp),
                    tags = note.tags
                )
            }

            if (note.title.isNotBlank()) {
                Text(
                    text = note.title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

            if (note.content.isNotBlank()) {
                Text(
                    text = note.content,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    maxLines = 8,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                )
            }

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))

            if ((note.selectedBackgroundImageIndex != 0) && (noteColor != MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(45.dp)
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                        .background(Color(noteColor.toArgb()))
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            shape = CircleShape
                        )
                )

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            }

            Text(
                text = "Created: ${convertTimestampToDate(note.createdDate)}",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall.copy(fontSize = 10.sp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                    .padding(bottom = 5.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalLayoutApi::class)
@Composable
fun TagList(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    tags: List<String>
) {
    FlowRow(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp),
    ) {
        tags.forEach {
            MyTag(text = it)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyTag(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(vertical = 3.dp)
            .clip(MaterialTheme.shapes.extraSmall)
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraSmall,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
            )
//            .background(
//                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
//            )
            .padding(horizontal = 6.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
    )
    {
        Text(
            text = text,
//            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
            fontSize = 15.sp
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun NoteItemPreview() {
    NoteItem(
        note = Note(
            title = "Title",
            content = "Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content ",
            tags = listOf(
                "Tag 1",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2",
                "Tag 2"
            ),
            lastModifiedDate = 2,
            createdDate = 1,
            selectedColorIndex = 4,
            selectedBackgroundImageIndex = 1
        ),
        onNoteItemClick = {}
    )
}


private fun convertTimestampToDate(timestamp: Long): String {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM h:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
    val date = Date(timestamp)
    return format.format(date)
}
```